# javascript global variables are not been exposed on ie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angular

I have a rails app, on my `app.html.erb` I define some global variables inside a script.

```
<script>
    var MY_CONST="<%= Setting.oauth.my_const -%>";
</script>
```

then on my angularjs code I reference this const.

```
params={
    my_const: MY_CONST    
};
```

This works fine to all browsers except IE, in console it gives me an error

```
MY_CONST is undefined.
```

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Ether your piece of angular code is executed before the  block is evaluated. Or the angular modules are scoped in a way that they don't have access to global variables.

Because when I just add this script tag to any page I can access the MY_CONST even in IE.

```
<script>
    var MY_CONST="<%= Setting.oauth.my_const -%>";
</script>
```

Comment: Yea it make sense, but the thing is that I don't get an error on the other browsers, only on IE.

Comment: Which IE version do you use for this?

Comment: It's version 11.

Comment: In the module you want to use, before @Component({...}  write: declare var MY_CONTS:any